# How to modify HTML in WordPress core file

Tags: html, wordpress, function, pagination, hook

I would like to modify some HTML stuffs in a function called **pagination()** in this Wordpress core file:

**wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php**

I have been searching for relevant hook which can be used to update HTML in the above function, but I have not found one.

Here are HTML I would like to change the last part of the followings:

```
      protected function pagination( $which ) {
        if ( empty( $this->_pagination_args ) ) {
          return;
        }

        $total_items     = $this->_pagination_args['total_items'];
        $total_pages     = $this->_pagination_args['total_pages'];
        $infinite_scroll = false;
        if ( isset( $this->_pagination_args['infinite_scroll'] ) ) {
          $infinite_scroll = $this->_pagination_args['infinite_scroll'];
        }

        if ( 'top' === $which && $total_pages > 1 ) {
          $this->screen->render_screen_reader_content( 'heading_pagination' );
        }

        // I would like to change this part of pagination():
        $output = '<span class="displaying-num">' . sprintf(
          /* translators: %s: Number of items. */
          _n( '%s item', '%s items', $total_items ),
          number_format_i18n( $total_items )
        ) . '</span>';
                    
         ..........................................
         ...........................................etc.
```

It should be:

```
        global $wp_query;
        $page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $ppp = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
        $end = $ppp * $page;
        $start = $end - $ppp + 1;
     //   $total = $wp_query->found_posts;
     //   echo "Showing posts $start through $end of $total total.";

        $output = '<span class="displaying-num">' . "Showing $start to $end of " . sprintf(
              /* translators: %s: Number of items. */
              _n( '%s item', '%s items', $total_items ),
              number_format_i18n( $total_items )
          ) . '</span>';
```

The above codes are used for the post list of a Custom Post Type on my WP website.

Can anyone please advise what hook should be for the above purpose?

Comment: You will need to be more specific about what HTML you want to modify. Also, WP_List_Table is not only a core class, it is a base table for all other tables, so you need to decide if you are trying to alter a specific instance, or all of them.

Comment: Hi Chis Haas, I have updated my post to reflect your advice. Thanks

Comment: thanks. To be very clear, do you want to change _every_ list table in WordPress? Plugins, users, pages, posts, links, media, sites, themes, application passwords, etc. Or are you wanting to change a specific instance only? Also, can you elaborate more specifically what you want to add? The WP List Table is a very complex object, and changes to it should be done very carefully. Also, it is sometimes better/easier to do this in JS, too.

Comment: No. I just updated my post correctly. I want to insert some php codes as well as HTML inside pagination() function. What hook should be? I put those codes above directly in the WP core file - they are working without issue. Well we cannot modify core files, that should be using a hook. Thanks

Comment: As I keep saying, "class-wp-list-table.php" is used by (almost) _every_ table in WordPress. So first you need to decide which of these you want to change. Is it a specific CPT? Pages or Posts? Or a custom table. If this is a custom table, that's actually pretty easy, you just override the method. But I'm assuming this is a default one. If that's the case, this is honestly pretty hard to do in PHP AFAIK. Instead I'd recommend tackling this in JS. You can get the current page size from `document.querySelector('[name="wp_screen_options[value]"]')`, and you should be able to find the others, too

Comment: Yes it is a Post List of Custom Post Type. I have updated my post as well. Many thanks for your support.